# core data crashed when save it to a directory created by myself in LibraryDirectory

Tags: core-data, path, crash

here is my code thar return a directory to save core data files.

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSString = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.triplec.WKCC" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    var libP = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).first! as NSString
    let path = libP.stringByAppendingPathComponent("coredata") as String
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) {
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch { }
    }
    print(path)
    return path as NSString
}()
```

when I called function below, it crashed. 
The crash log says that the file couldn’t be saved.

```
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite"))
do {
    try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
} catch {
    abort()
}
```

And when I did't append string to libP, it did work。
Anyone knows how to save core data files in a diretory created by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't even tested your code that's supposed to create the directory to see if it works. This code:

```
if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) {
    do {
        try fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch { }
}
```

...says that if the directory **already exists** then create it. But if the directory doesn't exist, do nothing.